# Parsing huge hive logs and storing in Hbase

Tags: hive, hbase, hiveql, logparser

I need to parse through the Hive logs generated by Yarn and store them in Hive or Hbase .The challenge here is the logs will be huge occupying upto 1 GB .So I need to parse them store the relevant information in Hbase .So what would be the best way to achieve it ?

Comment: Always include some code showing what you have tried.

Comment: 1GB really isn't that big in Hadoop land. If you want to process the logs in real time, consider a Spark Streaming/Kafka Streams job. Otherwise a batch Spark job will do the job.